# connecting android app to pc via wifi , exchanging informations

Tags: java, android, browser, android-wifi

My objective is to connect my ( android ) app to my pc, for instance something like AirDroid in which you can manipulate your phone using the (html,php,css, or javascript) 'webpage that it provides you through i.e. 192.168.0.5:8888 address.

another example is the whatsapp.web link.

I didn't find anything of this kind on the internet; 
I think I should do some sort of socket connection (ip:port)  but i don't know what kind of (android)background function i need to use to accomplish this task.

the hard part I think is the data exchanging  for example : I connect to 192.168.0.3:6666 it shows me a webpage in which there is a button and if I press it I want send a string to my app so my app can elaborate the string and do its stuff.

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT 17/09/2015 :

I found this : http://codeseekah.com/2012/08/07/port-forwarding-an-android-local-port/   it uses the tool netcat or nc to make a port available to the only  localhost. so the server side is the android phone.

and then i found this on wikipedia

**Setting up a one-shot webserver on port 8080 to present the content of a file:**

{ echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: $(wc -c

The file can then be accessed via a web browser under http://servername:8080/. Netcat only serves the file once to the first client that connects and then exits.

Am I going the right way ?

Comment: You can check out this project as a starting point. https://github.com/priyankvex/Socket-Remote . It connected pc and android phone using sockets.

Comment: mhh, this has a Server.jar program in order to do the client-server stuff that's not what i need. i don't want  pre-installed software on my computer to make this connection and exchange info

Comment: You need something to be running as server at the pc. It can be a website or a program like this one. For a website that can be opened in a browser. You can implement sockets in JS too.

Comment: for instace , how can i make an app that : you choose an address and a port like 192.168.0.4:6666 and the browser pop-up your page , is like whene you do the 192.168.0.1 stuff and appears the router configurations . maybe you are right but for now i don't understand your point of view

Comment: In your example "choose an address and a port like 192.168.0.4:6666 and the browser pop-up your page", you would have to have a web server running on the machine 192.168.0.4 at port 6666 it would accept the connection from the android device and send the html page.  There is no magic interface on a PC for your android to connect to. You have to provide some process like Server.jar that knows how to accept the connection and handle whatever communication protocol you decide to use.